# Where can I find the latest nightly build of the development version?

Tags: development, iso, release-management

I want to test out a kernel issue and see if it's corrected in the latest Natty release. The last alpha was a little bit ago and I thought there were nightly ISOs I could try instead, but I can't seem to find them.

Comment: You do know you can test the latest kernels without using the latest version of Ubuntu? For example, I'm running 2.6.38-rc7 on Maverick.

Comment: No, haven't seen that. Do you have a link I could check out?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the links:

- Live CD - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/
- Alternate CD - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/